# Apply two animation on one object in unity

Tags: unity, animation

I am looking for a perfect example to apply two animation on same object and to run those animations simultaneously. In my game, a player is jumping as well as flapping. As per my research, I have got something like this. create both animation in different layer in animator control and then blending those animations. But I could't do that as I can't understand it properly. I need an example that can solve my problem. And I am not importing animations from anywhere. I am creating it in unity only.
Hope for good example.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you play more than one animation at a time in Unity?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/122088/how-do-you-play-more-than-one-animation-at-a-time-in-unity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't understand your question but refer this URL to Create more then animation to one gameobject 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O_0gZuqW6y8

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=giSjcA109CE

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MtJhZ4pJXlM

Answer (score 0):

If possible, you could have 1 animation running on the actual object, and run the second on a parent object, since all the values in the parent object automatically transfer to the animating object. Just make sure that the parent animation doesn't use the child object for one of the animating "properties".